# Bundle inside bundle

Tags: product, bundled-product, products-management

So I was wondering how I go about back-ending this, im a fairly good developer just not sure how to tell Magento todo I guess CMS the data. So the products I have are 8 juices, you cannot buy the juices on their own, you have to purchase them as part of a pack of a configuration of 6 juices to make a pack. Each pack has its own price. Each one of these packs exist as part of a large product. So at a top down solution, there are 3 packs, standard, standard x, standard xl, each one of those packs contain, 3 packs of their own, 1 day, 3 day, and 5 day, and each one of those packs contain, 6 juices. Only the Day packs have prices associated to it. How do i go about doing this??

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand how your product logic, so I am not sure if bundle products are really the right type for you.

But regardless, Magento does not allow nested product types by design like "bundle in bundle" or "bundle in configurable". I worked on custom product types with this requirements and you certainly don't want to go down this road, it requires lots of rewrites in different places.

So try to model it with only one nesting level. For example using these bundles:

- Standard 1 day
- Standard 3 day
- Standard 5 day
- Standard X 1 day
- ...

You could write a custom product view template to show multiple bundles together as one product. Since you only have three main products, a little bit hard coding probably won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for something similar but it leverages some data we already have in our system. We have an attribute on products like this that contains a set of SKUs, one of which must be selected and purchased along with the parent item.

I'm going to make a Magento 2 Bundle Product containing all of the parent and children products in their respective sections, and then customize the customer's product view to show/hide valid options. So for example, the second section of a bundle would be hidden until the user selected a product from the first section. Once the user selects a product from the first section, I will reveal the items from the second section that match the first product's valid set of children SKUs, and leave the rest hidden.

This means Magento 2 will technically be okay with bundle products that we would consider invalid, however, users should only be capable of assembling valid bundle products.

---

Comment: Did you got any success in that because  I facing same issue

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. But I'll be sure to update when we tackle this task.